# Getting DMA USART to work on STM32L053R8T6

Tags: c, stm32, dma, usart

I am having an issue in getting my computer (virtual COM port, to be exact) to communicate with my STM32L053R8T6 (Nucleo) board by DMA and USART. Here is my code for the DMA and USART part:

```
#include "Device/Include/stm32l0xx.h"   // Device header
#include "JB.h"
#include <string.h>

#define PCLK    32000000
#define BAUD    19200

uint8_t stringtosend[] = "test\n";
uint8_t stringtoreceive[] = " ";

void ENABLE_UART_DMA(void){
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN; //enable periph.clk for DMA1

    /**Enabling DMA for transmission
     * DMA1, Channel 4 mapped for USART2TX
     * USART2 TDR for peripheral address
     * stringtosend for data address
     * Memory increment, memory to peripheral | 8-bit transfer | transfer complete interrupt**/
    DMA1_CSELR->CSELR = (DMA1_CSELR->CSELR & ~DMA_CSELR_C4S) | (4 << (3 * 4));
    DMA1_Channel4->CPAR = (uint32_t)&(USART2->TDR);
    DMA1_Channel4->CMAR = (uint32_t)stringtosend;
    DMA1_Channel4->CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_DIR | DMA_CCR_TCIE;

    /**Enabling DMA for reception
     * DMA1, Channel 5 mapped for USART2RX
     * USART2 RDR for peripheral address
     * stringtoreceive for data address
     * Data size given
     * Memory increment, peripheral to memory | 8-bit transfer | transfer complete interrupt**/
    DMA1_CSELR->CSELR = (DMA1_CSELR->CSELR & ~DMA_CSELR_C5S) | (4 << (4 * 4)); 
    DMA1_Channel5->CPAR = (uint32_t)&(USART2->RDR); 
    DMA1_Channel5->CMAR = (uint32_t)stringtoreceive;
    DMA1_Channel5->CNDTR = sizeof(stringtoreceive);
    DMA1_Channel5->CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_EN;

    NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_5_6_7_IRQn, 0); //NVIC enabled, max priority, channels 4-7
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_5_6_7_IRQn);
}

void CONFIGURE_UART_PARAM(void){
  RCC->IOPENR  |= ( 1ul <<  0); //Enable GPIOA clock
  RCC->APB1ENR |= ( 1ul << 17); //Enable USART#2 clock

  GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~((15ul << 4* 3) | (15ul << 4* 2) ); //Clear PA2,PA3
  GPIOA->AFR[0] |=  (( 4ul << 4* 3) | ( 4ul << 4* 2) ); //Set   PA2,PA3
  GPIOA->MODER  &= ~(( 3ul << 2* 3) | ( 3ul << 2* 2) ); //Same as above
  GPIOA->MODER  |=  (( 2ul << 2* 3) | ( 2ul << 2* 2) );

    USART2->BRR = PCLK/BAUD;
    USART2->CR3 = USART_CR3_DMAT | USART_CR3_DMAR; //Enable DMA mode in transmit and receive

    /*UART enabled for transmission and reception*/
  USART2->CR1 = USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_UE; 

  while((USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TC) != USART_ISR_TC)
  { 
    /* add time out here for a robust application */
  }
  USART2->ICR = USART_ICR_TCCF;
}

void CONFIGURE_EXTI(void){
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = ((SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] & 0x0000) | SYSCFG_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC); //clear EXTICR and set to PC13(B1)
    EXTI->FTSR |= EXTI_FTSR_TR13; //falling edge trigger
    EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_IM13; //unmask
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0); //def interrupt
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);
}

/*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
/*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
/*Interrupt Handlers*/

void DMA1_Channel4_5_6_7IRQHandler(void){
    if((DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIF4) == DMA_ISR_TCIF4){
    DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CTCIF4; //Clear Channel 4 Transfer Complete flag
  }
  else if((DMA1->ISR & DMA_ISR_TCIF5) == DMA_ISR_TCIF5){
    DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CTCIF5; //Clear Channel 5 Transfer Complete flag

    DMA1_Channel5->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;
    DMA1_Channel5->CNDTR = sizeof(stringtoreceive);/* Data size */
    DMA1_Channel5->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;
  }
}

void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void){
  if(!(GPIOC->IDR & (1 << 13))){
    /* Clear EXTI 13 flag */
    EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PIF13;

    /* start 8-bit transmission with DMA */
    DMA1_Channel4->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN; //channel disable
    DMA1_Channel4->CNDTR = sizeof(stringtosend);/* Data size */
    DMA1_Channel4->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN; //channel enable
  }
}

//void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void){
//  if((EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PIF13) == EXTI_PR_PIF13){
//    /* Clear EXTI 13 flag */
//    EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PIF13;
//  
//    /* start 8-bit transmission with DMA */
//    DMA1_Channel4->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN; //channel disable
//    DMA1_Channel4->CNDTR = sizeof(stringtosend);/* Data size */
//    DMA1_Channel4->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN; //channel enable
//  }
//}
```

Now then, this specific code is based on an example from the STM32L0 snippets package 1.20, USART/Communcation Using DMA. USART 1 was simply redefined to USART 2 (as that is the one used by the virtual COM port), and the DMA channels were redefined according to that as well. However, the problem here is very simple: it will only print stringtosend once (would like to do it every time button B1 is pressed), and will not receive data by RX either - as if it completely ignores the DMA interrupt handler - which I am not sure how to test (no trace features available on this board). What I have seems to reflect the reference manual well enough, and all the main does is:

```
int main(){

SystemCoreClockInit();
CONFIGURE_UART_PARAM();
ENABLE_UART_DMA();
pushbutton_def();
CONFIGURE_EXTI();

while(1){
}
```

...which should just react to the defined interrupts, however it does not, and for the life of me, I cannot see why. I would love if you could help me - I would also like to avoid HAL or LL APIs - this is not a complex enough project to warrant their usage (several inputs, outputs, comms between two boards by USART/DMA), plus I would prefer to learn working closer to the register level.

Thanks!

**edit (in response to Berendi's suggestions):**
1. GPIOC was defined in another file, called with pushbutton_def():

```
RCC->IOPENR |= (1UL << 2); //enable GPIOC
```

2. I understand exactly what you mean by your explanation (indeed, the register referred by those two is "the same", 0x00000020U), but I am not sure as to how to redefine it: here is my attempt after looking at the reference manual (SYSCFG part) and the source (still, it does not work):

   SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] = ((SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] & 0x0000) | SYSCFG_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC);
3. As suggested, I have added `USART2->ICR = USART_ICR_TCCF;` to the EXTIhandler, right after the DMA channels. I have kept it in the USART definition. The message is still only being sent once, though.

Answer (score 1):

**`GPIOC` is not enabled**

Here,

```
RCC->IOPENR  |= ( 1ul <<  0); //Enable GPIOA clock
```

you should enable `GPIOC` too.

**`EXTI13` is mapped to `PA13`**

Here,

```
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] = ((SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] & 0x0000) | SYSCFG_EXTICR4_EXTI13_PC); //clear EXTICR and set to PC13(B1)
```

you are setting the configuration register for `EXTI0`-`EXTI3`, actually mapping **`EXTI1` to `PC1`**. `EXTI13` remains mapped to `PA13`, which is actually `SWDIO`, connected to the onboard debugger. I guess the traffic on `SWDIO` triggers the EXTI interrupt, the handler checks `PC13` which is always reading 0 because the port is disabled, and enables DMA. DMA transmit works only once though, because

**`USART_ISR_TC` is not cleared in the interrupt**

but only once at startup. You should move this line

```
USART2->ICR = USART_ICR_TCCF;
```

to the EXTI interrupt handler.

I'm not sure why receiving doesn't work, perhaps the DMA handler has no chance to run, because EXTI is constantly retriggered by SWD traffic. Both interrupts have the same priority, the one with lower interrupt number wins, which is the EXTI handler. If it's always retriggered before it finishes, then it will be called again, not letting the other handler to run.

Comment: Hi berendi. Thanks for your suggestions and patience, I am still facing the same issues, and I have added my implementation of your suggestions into my post.